# RSA encryption + Objective-C using Transforms/Security.framework

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, encryption, cryptography, openssl

I am attempting to use RSA public key encryption to encrypt a AES+CBC key over a network, however I'm having trouble finding the right tools or setup in order to achieve my goal.

I've been looking over at the Transforms API, which is perfectly capable of using RSA for signing/verifying data, but have thus far been unable to figure out how to utilize it for encrypting itself.

My question is therefore as follows: Am I stuck with libcrypto/OpenSSL or is what I'm trying to accomplish actually still possible with the API? The goal being using `SecEncryptTransformCreate' etc. to use RSA rather than AES/Symmetric encryption.

Answer (score 1):

SecEncryptTransformCreate seems to support both PKCS#1 (v1.5, although it doesn't say) and OAEP padding, according to the API. I've also seen some samples for the (more secure) [OAEP padding](http://www.cybertechquestions.com/java-to-objective-c-rsa-implementation_566741.html).

Again, the API does not seem to specify RSA anywhere, but PKCS#1 padding and OAEP padding [are RSA specific encryption schemes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447).

So you seem to be looking at the [correct API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/System/Reference/SecEncryptTransform_header_reference/Reference/reference.html) to use. Note that to encrypt larger amounts of plain text you should be using hybrid encryption (both AES and RSA).